# Journey Builder decision split on a date logic

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a journey with a decision split on a date field. However it's rejecting what I assume to be valid entrants to this path.

Can anyone see a issue with the logic of this decision or has anyone experienced a similar issue when using data with a AUS format.

The decision is:

Date is after today

AND

Date is before today + 2 days

Which going off todays date the 2/08/2017 this should allow those with a date of either the 03/08/2017 or 04/08/2017 to be eligible for this path.

However when running this as a test this decision path is not picking up a record with a date of 03/08/2017

Note: The date field in question is sourced from "Contact Data" from "MobileConnect"

Comment: You need to be mindful regardless of what dates you set at a data extension level, the system dates will always be set in UTC time which is 16 hours behind Australia give or take based on daylight savings. so in theory it is 01/08/2017 right now in Marketing cloud since it is the 02/08/2017 for Australia

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherHaddad so by the sounds of it the solution is either to have the decisions filter operate is such as way that the 16 hour gap doesn't matter or using a query - 16 to the date I'm feeding in. Is that about right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, if you are happy with my answer, let me know and I can add it so you can mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: Sure am! @ChristopherHaddad add it up and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks for your assistance with this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take note of what dates you set at a data extension level, the system dates will always be set in CST time which is 16 hours behind Australia give or take based on daylight savings.

Comment: Hi there, im pretty sure the system dates are in CST (Central Standard Time non-daylight saving observing), which would be about-16 hours Im guessing, not UTC :D

Comment: @Doug yes you are right, I had a typo actually, I will fix that up.