# Journey Builder re-entry

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, subscriber

I just want to clarify the following:

we are trying to create the journey which lasts exactly one month (1.11.18-30.11.18) which means basically 5 emails. We want to send an email to our subscribers each week, but is that possible so that subscriber, who subscribed to our newsletter on 3rd of November gets emails starting from the second one and not the first one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it indeed necessary to use JB? You can do the same with a series of scheduled Guided Sends.

Comment: I agree - unless there's some kind of split going on, Journey Builder sounds like it would be getting in the way of your goal.

Answer (score 0):

While i agree with [Lukas](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237583/journey-builder-re-entry#comment361317_237583), i believe this could be completed with a decision split on "Join Date" before each Email Send, and for each email you want to be affected by the skip on entry date, where they would join just after the email is sent.

Read more here

[Journey Builder decision split on a date logic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186868/journey-builder-decision-split-on-a-date-logic)

[Journey and Contact Data in Decision Splits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm)